# I can't find any formula to solve this differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

$$\frac{dx}{dt} + x^2 = B + A\cdot e^{C\ln\big(\frac{x}{x_0}\big)+\ln(x_0)}, \quad x(t_0)=x_0$$

Can anyone please help me where I can start from this equation?

I simplified a complicated equation and I am currently stuck.

I looked back at my differential equation textbook and could not find a single formula to solve it. Most of the formula that I am seeing are function of $t$ but in this equation is $x$.

Please help to start with something.

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, done

Comment: what do you exspect? a analytical solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hint... You can simplify the exponential term and write the equation as

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = -x^2 + B + A x_0 \left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right)^C,
$$

which is a separable variable DE. However the method of solution will depend on the value of $C$.

Comment: right. Thank you so much. I just need to simpliy more.

Comment: We have $dt/dx=(-x^2+B+A x^C x_0^{1-C})^{-1}$